# Retrofit enqueue in a loop is too slow

Tags: android, retrofit

This is more of an architecture type of question.
I am using retrofit enqueue method in a loop to make about 200 http get requests (each iteration one request), but it takes about 10 seconds to finish them all. I want to load all the data in the splash screen, so 10 seconds is too much. Is there a better method, without having to use threading libraries?

Comment: Will be hard to improve that without running those requests asynchronously in the background

Comment: Doesn't enqueue method run requests asynchronously in the background? What do you mean?

Comment: Make your request in the background and get from local database first. Then after that save all data to local DB. Second time will be faster than first time

Comment: @shohruhMaxmudov That would suggest that I can update the UI dynamically, but I can't because ViewModel lags the googlemap with LiveData updates. That's why I need to preload data in the splash screen, before the map launches.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of data would you load? So 200 http get requests is normal to take about 10 seconds. Maybe you can use a remote database, firebase is easy and very fast!

Comment: Air pollution data from government API. I'm glad to hear that it's normal, because I thought I may have coded it wrong. Thank you for suggesting Firebase, I am already exploring it.

Comment: Ok, nice! I'm sure you can find a great solution! Just keep walking...